# How can I manipulate the data in Spring Boot Test class so that it is updated on the Server as well? (Integration testing, Selenium)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, selenium-webdriver, spring-boot-test

I want to make an integration **Selenium** test of my **Spring Boot Web application**, however I can't figure out how to **update** the object inside my test class, so that the server would use the **updated version** of it.

Basically, the question is how to connect the object "**ad**" with the same object on the server side?

```
@DirtiesContext
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
public class IntegrationTest {
    // this field I want to update during the testing, so that the server knows about it
    @Autowired
    AppData ad;
    @Autowired
    AppLogic logic;
    @LocalServerPort
    int port;

    private WebDriver driver;
    private ChromeOptions options;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws InterruptedException {
        // SpringApplication.run(Application.class);

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");
        options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        options.setBinary("D:\\chrome.exe");
    }

    public void test() {
        // loading the browser and connecting to the server
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("http://localhost:8081");

        // here I want to rig and manipulate the data, which the server is using ("ad" object),
        // but the problem is it does not affect it on the server side
        ad.getPlayers();
        ad.setCards("rigged data");
    }
}
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
@Controller
public class AppController {
    AppLogic logic;
    AppData ad;

    public AppController(AppLogic logic, AppData ad) {
        this.logic = logic;
        this.ad = ad;
    }

    // ...
}
```

```
@Component
public class AppLogic {
    // ...
}
```

```
public interface AppData {
    // ...
}
```

```
@Component
public class AppDataImpl implements AppData {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've figured out it was just a silly mistake, I should have used a @LocalServerPort field in order to connect to the server, which is:

```
@LocalServerPort
int port;
```

So connecting to the server should take the following form:

```
driver.get("http://localhost:" + port);
```

This way all necessary data are injected properly, so that we can manipulate it in our tests.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are trying to do two different things at same time.. You need to understand Selenium is used for automation of web UI, if you want to perform some other tasks or processing other than that, you have to work with some other libraries/packages. In this you want to work with Spring Boot, which is to create BackEnd end points.. For that you can work with [RestAssured](https://rest-assured.io/) or [UniRest](http://kong.github.io/unirest-java/).

Comment: Thank you, but I am pretty sure one can use both Selenium and Spring Boot at the same time. Selenium for UI automation and Spring for asserting the values of object's fields after some automated actions.